# Structs on the stack (ANSI C)

Tags: c, memory, 64-bit, stack

Having started to study Ulrich Dreppers "What every programmer should know about memory"  [1] series I got stuck when trying to reproduce the examples presented in section

3.3.2 Measurements of Cache Effects

As far as I understand the structures should be allocated on the stack since then they are in memory one after another. Verifying this with a small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMPAD 0

struct listelement
{ 
    struct listelement *next;
    long int padding[NUMPAD];
};

typedef struct listelement elem;

int main()
{
    int size_elem = sizeof(elem);
    printf("Size of a list elem: %i\n", size_elem);

    elem _1, _2, _3;

    _1.next = &_2;
    _2.next = &_3;
    _3.next = &_1;

    elem *first, *last, *curr;

    first = &_1;
    last = &_3;
    curr = &_1;

    int k=0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Element at %p", curr);
        for (int i=0; i<NUMPAD; i++)
        {
            (curr->padding)[i] = i+k;
            printf("%ld ", (curr->padding)[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        if (curr == last)
            break;
        k++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When running the program the output is:

```
Size of a list elem: 8
Element at 0x7fff5fbff540
Element at 0x7fff5fbff530
Element at 0x7fff5fbff520
```

The differences between the memory addresses, however is 16 why not 8? When increasing NUMPAD the difference seems to grow even more, for example for NUMPAD=2 I get a difference of 511.

I did the tests on a macbook pro running OSX 10.6 64bit.

[1] http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/

Update: I also played with incrementing/decrementing the pointers. It seems to work in 32bit mode, but not in 64bit mode. Adding the code

```
first--;
printf("first-- %p\n", first);
if (first == &_2) {
    printf("Decrementing works.\n");
}

macbook:blah nils$ gcc -m32 -DNUMPAD=0 -g -std=c99 -o blah blah.c && ./blah
Size of a list elem: 4
Element at 0xbffff5b8
Element at 0xbffff5b4
Element at 0xbffff5b0
first-- 0xbffff5b4
Decrementing works.
macbook:blah nils$ gcc -DNUMPAD=0 -g -std=c99 -o blah blah.c && ./blah
Size of a list elem: 8
Element at 0x7fff5fbff530
Element at 0x7fff5fbff520
Element at 0x7fff5fbff510
first-- 0x7fff5fbff528
```

I wonder how this makes sense.. maybe I should just place all the structs into an array.

Comment: Try to compile with -pedantic-errors. It's invalid standard C code... You can have array[] in struct/union. But not 0 element array.

Comment: I know, but that does not seem to be the problem

Comment: Yes, you definitely should place the structs in an array if you have any expectation that they'll be adjacent. Note that the Dreppers article itself says "The program *creates an array* corresponding to the working set size of elements of this type"

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory warning: in general, you should not be making any assumptions about the relative location in memory of independent variables (i.e., ones that are not wrapped up inside an array or struct). The compiler is allowed to lay out variables on the stack as it sees fit, subject to the alignment restrictions of the struct members.

That said, I think you will find that if you change:

```
printf("Element at %p", curr)
```

to

```
printf("Element at %p\n", curr)
```

Your output will make a lot more sense.

Comment: Is it? Also for the stack? But the have to be aligned in memory, otherwise the tests, which are described in 3.3.2 Measurements of Cache Effect make no sense..

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer. Relative location of independent variables is completely up to the implementation. Of course Drepper's article was trying to teach programmers about the behavior of a particular implementation, so it would be interesting to see why there's this apparent discrepency.

Answer (score 1):

read this:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html

I suspect the [0] defaults to [] and has size 0 if you are compiling using C99

Answer (score 0):

A zero-length array invokes undefined behavior, so you're lucky it didn't compile to `system("rm -rf /");`...

Comment: Even with NUMPAD=1, I got 0x7F difference on a 32 bit machine. It became 0x1ff with NUMPAD=2

Comment: its not about zero length arrays - see my answer. @Anders

Comment: OK, well I suppose Drepper is just wrong. It certainly [wouldn't be a first](http://www.uclibc.org/downloads/Glibc_vs_uClibc_Differences.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
printf("%ld ", (curr->padding)[i]);
```

to

```
printf("\t%ld ", (curr->padding)[i]);
```

and try again - got it?

Here are my results (on a 32 bit machine) with various values for `NUMPAD`.

```
test $ gcc -std=c99 -DNUMPAD=0 test.c && ./a.out 
Size of a list elem: 4
Element at 0xbfd84df8
Element at 0xbfd84df4
Element at 0xbfd84df0
test $ gcc -std=c99 -DNUMPAD=1 test.c && ./a.out 
Size of a list elem: 8
Element at 0xbff7eff4   0 
Element at 0xbff7efec   1 
Element at 0xbff7efe4   2 
test $ gcc -std=c99 -DNUMPAD=2 test.c && ./a.out 
Size of a list elem: 12
Element at 0xbf9ea260   0   1 
Element at 0xbf9ea254   1   2 
Element at 0xbf9ea248   2   3
```

Comment: Thx for pointing that out, oversaw that I forgot to put a space (or tab), however in the case where NUMPAD=0 it does not change anything. Also did you try this on Linux?

Comment: If I compile it for 32bit, the differences between the addresses are the same as above: It's matching the size of elem, strange..